# Run VBA code if the cell value true or equel to number only

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel sheet which contain dynamic cell range name list(Picked)name manager. When I click any cell from that list vba code shows active cell value in another cell. I want run this vba code if `$d$2 = 1` only.

VBA code as below.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Application.Intersect(ActiveCell, [Picked]) Is Nothing Then
        [ValPicked] = ActiveCell.Value
     End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add another `If`, and use `Target` in your code rather than `ActiveCell`. The former is the cell that has been changed.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Application.Intersect(Target, [Picked]) Is Nothing Then
        If Range("D2").Value = 1 Then
            [ValPicked] = Target.Value
        End If
     End If
End Sub
```

Comment: It's my pleasure.